# Is there a way to implement this libraries in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have found two libraries that do the same thing but one for Xamarin Android and one for Xamarin iOS.
Is there a way to implement these libraries and use them in Xamarin Forms?

I'm trying to make an emoji keyboard but can't find documentation for Xamarin Forms. These libraries do exactly what I want to do but I don't know if it is possible to implement them in my Xamarin Forms project.

[Xamarin Android Library](https://github.com/giuseppenovielli/Xamarin.Android-Emojicon)

[Xamarin iOS Library](https://github.com/giuseppenovielli/Xamarin.iOS-EmojKeyboard)

Comment: If you want to display an emoji keyboard directly when user click the Entry , you could create a custom view with the list of emojis (you could use bindable layout  or CollectionView to fill the CustomView) . Or you can search on nuget if there is such a similar plugin .

Comment: In nuget I didn't find anything for Xamarin Forms. I tried to create a frame with a collectionView inside, and inside the datatemplate an imagebutton. The problem I have when using the frame is that when I switch between the keyboard and the frame, when the keyboard is opened it moves the application up and then when switch to the frame, the frame does not move it and the change is not smooth.

Comment: This is how it looks with the frame: https://gyazo.com/f8f02653c42eb3f0f200a3971ad6e02e

Comment: Set the entry as a label then set the text when you click the emoji keyboard